# Access to static member by non-static method

Tags: c++

This must be very trivial, but I can't find it out:

```
struct Test {
  static int n;
  void Save(int val) {
    Test::n = val;
  }
};

int main() {
  Test t;
  t.Save(2);
  return 0;
}
```

Why there is undefined reference to `Test::n` at line 4?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define the static:

```
struct Test {
  static int n;
  void Save(int val) {
    Test::n = val;
  }
};

int Test::n = 0;
```

Note that the definition must appear in an implementation file, not a header, otherwise you'll get a multiple definition error.

Comment: Start typing slower to give others a chance :p 14 seconds is too low to compete with.

Comment: Hmm isn't he initializing it in line 4?

Comment: +1 but the relevant point for the OP is the *definition* not the initialisation. In particular, C++11 allows initialisation inline, but the definition must still be in the header.

Comment: @ametren, that's inside a function. A non-static one at that. It's just assigning a value.

Comment: @ametren that's assignment, not initialization.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a java guy, but I still don't understand why you can't assign a value to an uninitialized static from inside a non-static method.  He's not trying to read the value.

Comment: @ametren those are the rules. The variable needs to be defined (initialized was used in haste here).

Comment: Yup, thanks, I think the define vs. initialize mistake was confusing me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *define* the static data member (not necessarily *initialize* it). It will be initialized to 0 automatically. I suppose you're getting a linker error. This is because due to the missing definition, the data member has not been allocated. This has nothing to do with its value.